Intersection of Gelfand-Shilov spaces
Recall the following definition of Gelfand-Shilov spaces:
the space ${S_{\sigma,h}^s}$ is defined as
$$S_{\sigma,h}^s:=\left\{f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R): \sup \frac{\|x^\beta\partial_\alpha f\|_\infty}{h^{\alpha+\beta}\alpha^{s\alpha}\beta^{\sigma\beta}}<\infty\right\},$$
equipped with the obvious norm $\|f\|_{S_{\sigma,h}^s}$. From this, we define the space $S^{s}_\sigma$ as the inductive limit of $S^s_{\sigma,h}$ as $h\to \infty$ and $\Sigma^s_{\sigma}$ as the projective limit with $h\to 0$.
Now, it is clear that $$S^1_1\subseteq \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \Sigma_{1+\varepsilon}^{1+\varepsilon}.$$
My question is: is this inclusion proper? I think this is indeed the case, and I have tried 2 different ways of proving it, but both have failed (certainly due to my own ignorance)

The RHS can be topologized as the projective limit of the respective $\Sigma^{1+\frac1n}_{1+\frac1n}$, hence it is a Frechet space. If the LHS were barreled, for example, then I could argue that the 2 sets being equal would imply the topologies would coincide and try to obtain a contradiction from there but I am not sure whether the LHS is indeed barreled (while it is an LB space, it is not a strict LB space so the conclusion is not trivial)
All function in $S^1_1$ are real-analytic, hence it would suffice to construct a non-analytic element in the RHS. I thought of trying something like $e^{-x^2}f(x)$ where $f$ is a bounded smooth non-analytic function, but it is difficult to control the behaviour of such a function on both the space and the frequency side strictly enough so as to get $e^{-x^2}f(x)\in \text{RHS}$

